# logic or JavaScript error? array[x] undefined after pushing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic, minimax

I'm trying to code the AI for a tic-tac-toe game.
The full code is here: http://jsbin.com/tiweniludoqe/10/edit?js,console,output
I'm trying to keep an array with the "scores" of a possible move the AI can make on the line:
`moveScoreArray[initialMoveNum] += scoreStack.pop();`
but the console is saying `moveScoreArray[initialMoveNum]` is undefined. Is this a logic error or does JavaScript not allow passing the scores to the array like I'm doing here.

```
function minimax(inputBoard, player, availableMoves, steps) {
    var copyBoard = inputBoard.clone();

    if(availableMoves === 0) {
        console.log("tie");
        scoreStack.push(0);
    } else if(player < 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if(copyBoard[i][j] !== 0) {
                    j++;
                } else {
                    copyBoard[i][j] = -1;
                    if (checkForWin(copyBoard) < 0) {
                        scoreStack.push(-10);
                        //free up board for next for-loop iteration.
                        copyBoard[i][j] = 0;
                    } else {
                        minimax(copyBoard, 1, availableMoves - 1, steps++);
                        //free up the board for next for-loop iteration.
                        copyBoard[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //after finding all outcomes check if we're back to the initial step
        //if this is one of the AI's initial moves then add it's score to an Array of scores.
        if(availableMoves - steps === 1) {
            var initialMoveNum = moveScoreArray.length;
            while(scoreStack.length !== 0) {
                moveScoreArray[initialMoveNum] += scoreStack.pop();
                //console.log(scoreStack[scoreStack.length - 1]);
            }
                console.log("moveScoreArray value of initial move x: " + moveScoreArray[initialMoveNum]);
        }
    } else if(player > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if(copyBoard[i][j] !== 0) {
                    j++;
                } else {
                    copyBoard[i][j] = 1;
                    if (checkForWin(copyBoard) > 0) {
                        scoreStack.push(10);
                        copyBoard[i][j] = 0;
                    } else {
                        minimax(copyBoard, -1, availableMoves - 1, steps++);
                        copyBoard[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Global variables:

```
//keep track of the number of moves made
var moveNumber = 0;
//create a game board
var board = [];
//populate the board with arrays filled with zeroes
var board = [rOne = initArray(3, 0),
             rTwo = initArray(3, 0),
             rThree = initArray(3, 0)];
//number of total available moves
var totalMoves = board.length * board.length;

//fill an array with zeroes
function initArray(length, value) {
    var arr = [], i = 0;
    arr.length = length;
    for(i; i < length; i++) {
      arr[i] = value;
    }
    return arr;
}
//an array used as a stack to hold scores for moves
var scoreStack = [];
//an array to keep scores for each initial move the AI can make
var moveScoreArray = [];
```

Comment: Is `moveScoreArray` defined somewhere else? It looks like you are trying to get the length of a non-existent array, and subsequently set the index of a non-existent array as well.

Comment: Yeah it's defined as a global. I'll add the globals to this page.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
var ar = [1,2,3]
ar[ar.length] += 3;
```

would never work

```
var initialMoveNum = moveScoreArray.length;
moveScoreArray[initialMoveNum] += scoreStack.pop();
```

would never work.

Comment: After testing what you said, `var ar=[]` then `ar[ar.length] += "stuff"` the result of ar[0] is then "undefinedstuff". I didn't realized the array's "empty" spots held undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized array holds undefined values. So adding numbers to it results in NaN. Ex:

```
var ar = [];
var ar[ar.length] += "someText";
console.log(ar[0]);
```

results in the output "undefinedsomeText"

```
var ar = [];
var ar[ar.length] += 33;
console.log(ar[0]);
```

results in NaN